# Why does QPushButton example program "freeze up" until another window is pressed (Mac OS Catalina)?

Tags: macos, user-interface, pyqt5, qthread, qpushbutton

I've got what is probably a very basic question as a newbie to PyQt5. I see behavior where if I try to create actions based on a QPushButton, those actions don't take place until I go and click on the another window. This could be the terminal window I started the example in, or any other application window. I thought it was my code but I see the same behavior with the example [on this help site](https://wiki.qt.io/Qt_for_Python_Tutorial_ClickableButton)

```
import random
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui

class MyWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self)

        self.hello = ["Hallo Welt", "你好，世界", "Hei maailma",
            "Hola Mundo", "Привет мир"]

        self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Click me!")
        self.text = QtWidgets.QLabel("Hello World")
        self.text.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)

        self.layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.text)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.button)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

        self.button.clicked.connect(self.magic)


    def magic(self):
        self.text.setText(random.choice(self.hello))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    widget = MyWidget()
    widget.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

To duplicate, start the app from a terminal window. Resize the app window a bit (seems to trigger the behavior). Then press the button a few times. You'll see that the button action does not take effect until you click another window. I'm sure this reflects a basic lack of understanding of how the GUI event loop works in PyQt5, but it appears not to be easy to find good documentation on using PyQt5.

I'm on Mac OS Catalina

Comment: add `self.text.repaint()` after  `self.text.setText(random.choice(self.hello))`

Comment: That works. At least two pieces of example code omit this. Do you know why? Also, how do I map the C++ documentation to PyQt? - having trouble understanding this. I'm an experienced C++ guy but new to Qt.

Comment: No, the code is correct but there is a bug that affects MacOS: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-68521

Comment: The bug report say the bug has been fixed. Also, I have the same problem with matplotlib FigureCanvas. I have to call repaint(), update() doesn't work. It's all a bit disconcerting.